# FQL get liked artists

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Is it possible, using FQL, to get the liked artists(music) of a user? I check the permissions and I couldn't find anything related to it and I am not a facebook user so I am not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert Thanks for the response - Haven't had time to check it out, sorry about that - Will let you know today!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Like`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like) table doesn't give back the **interests**, but:

> An FQL table that returns the IDs of users who like a given object
>   (video, note, link, photo, or album).

That's not what we need.

### First way - Rapid description

In the [`User`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user) table, you'll find a `music` field which sends back one line containing all the liked artists. The query would be as easy as:

```
SELECT music FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```

---

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "music": "Macarize, MARCEL DETTMANN, Alan Fitzpatrick"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Second way - Detailed results

By the [`Page_fan`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan) table we get the user's music interests one by one.

```
SELECT name, type FROM page WHERE page_id IN (
    SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() AND profile_section="music")
```

---

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Macarize", 
      "type": "RECORD LABEL"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "MARCEL DETTMANN", 
      "type": "PRODUCER"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Alan Fitzpatrick", 
      "type": "MUSICIAN/BAND"
    }
  ]
}
```