# Using Open Graph API, can I retrieve the list of artists a user likes?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have found on SOF how to retrieve a list of a friends' likes (with permission of course). 
How do I retrieve specific likes ? I want likes about music only.

Any help would be appreciated.

best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no graph api version, previously answered for FQL here: [FQL get liked artists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035638/fql-get-liked-artists)